# required attribute in <textarea> doesn't work in chrome. It is a chrome's bug or I missed something?

Tags: html, google-chrome, attributes, textarea, required

this is a test code :

```html
<form method="post" action="somepage.php">
  <input type="text" name="test_input" required />
  <textarea name="test_textarea" required></textarea>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

It works well in firefox, but not in chrome / edge. Hovering the  let a message appears (the field is required), but not with the textarea.

thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Given the live demo in your question: If I fill i the text input and click submit, the textarea gets a message saying "Please fill in this field." in Chrome 103.0.5060.53 / Mac.

Comment: Well the main purpose of the required attribute is validation: You cannot submit the form without filling the field. This works in Chrome as well. So the only detail missing is the native tooltip.

Comment: The problem is not really the validation, but the message not showing when hovering the textarea element. (when you hover the input, a message appears, and should appears too with textarea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of `required` attribute is to run a validation when submitting, which works fine in both browsers.

[Chrome not showing the tooltip for `<textarea>` is a known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1339750&q=required%20textarea%20hover&can=2).

Comment: It's me that add it, but I was not sure if it was really a bug or Iif I did something wrong!

Comment: Haha, I see. Well personally I would agree that it’s a bug, since behaviour should be the same between `<input>` and `<textarea>`. Afaik there is no standard requiring or recommending this tooltip, though.